# Rails ActionMailer sends email but it does not show up as a sent email in the mailbox used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

I am using namecheap to send emails and it uses privateemail.

My setup in ActionMailer is:

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'mail.privateemail.com',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'privateemail.com',
  user_name:            'very@cool.com',
  password:             "very_secret",
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

As they say here:

https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/1179/2175/general-private-email-configuration-for-mail-clients-and-mobile-devices/

Now it sends the emails, but when I login in the web client, it does not show any mails sent in the sent folder.

Why is that ?

Answer (score 0):

SMTP delivery means sending an email and not send an email and store it in sent folder. This has to be done by the client additionally!

Comment: by client you mean Privateemail ?

Comment: Yes and no. I don't know if that is possible. Putting sent mails into a special folder after delivery is usually done by the client software, e.g. the web mail tool or your desktop client like thunderbird or something else. In the described scenario it should be done by ActionMailer, but I actually don't know if ActionMailer can do this. If the sent mails are needed as copy may be adding self as bcc is a workaround.